# Issues with running method in separate file when importing module

Tags: python, python-module

Wanted to import Car module but I can't seem to call the method. I have checked to see whether the files are in the same directory. There are no errors though. Just Process finished with exit code 0.

```
class Car():
"""A simple attempt to define a car"""
def __init__(self, make, model, year):
    """Initializing attributes of car"""
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
    self.odometer_reading = 0

def get_descriptive_name(self):
    """Method to return long name of any car"""
    Long_name = f'{self.make} {self.model} {self.year}'
    return Long_name

def read_odometer_self(self):
    """Method to read odometer reading"""
    print(f'This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles in it.')
```

This is my_car.py

```
from Car import Car

my_new_car = Car('Audi,', 'a4', 2016)
my_new_car.odometer_reading = 23
my_new_car.read_odometer_self()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you getting an error when instancing the object or only when you try to call its methods? I see you're missing indentation in the class definition but I'll assume that's just SO and that you have that right.

Comment: this works perfectly for me. Once I fixed the aforementioned indentation issue. Are you sure the latest version of Car.py is the correct directory, and you don't have an old version of Car.py in the correct directory that just doesn't happen to print ?

Comment: It works fine for me. A few minor things however, you can indent the comment after you've declared the car class and you can remove the () for the class because you aren't declaring any parameters.

Comment: You need to indent the methods of the Car class (`__init__`, `get_descriptive_name`, `read_odometer_self` [why you name it like this and not just `read_odometer`??])

Comment: @tralph. I've got issues with both instancing the object and calling its methods.

Comment: @JeffUK. Roger will check.

Comment: @ManishJoyeuse I just copy pasted the code in different files and it's working no issues, so on the coding side of things everything's correct. Are you using some sort of IDE that may be causing issues? Maybe you need to set up the path for the current directory? Are you getting import errors? Does running this with python directly work?